# fetching sum of a column with other columns in a single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having a problem in creating a mysql query.

There are two table t1 and t2.

**t1 table has following columns**

```
id, (primary key)
qty,
type (either 'pb' or 'hb')
```

**t2 column has follwing columns**

```
id, (foreign key of t1 table)
pb, (contains the amount)
hb, (contains the amount)
```

Now in the **type** column of t1 table there can be either of the values 'pb' and 'hb' (which you can see are the columns in the t2 table).

Now I want all the records containing the following columns

**id, qty, amount, and sum of the amount column**
I am successful in getting id,qty,amount using the following query

```
select  t1.id,t1.qty,case type when 'pb' then t2.pb else t2.hb end as amount from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

But I do not know how to get the sum of the amount column that is generated after this query and I have to do this using a single query or procedure ?

Can anyone help me please ??

Suppose t1 table has data

```
id|qty| type
1 | 4 | pb
2 | 6 | hb
```

and t2 table has data

```
id | pb | hb
1 | 300 | 500
2 | 400 | 600
```

what I want is

```
id | qty | amount
1 | 4 | 300
2 | 6 | 600
```

and total sum of amount column ie `900`

Comment: Can you add sample data and desired results to your question?  I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added the sample data. PLease check

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
select t1.id, t1.qty,
       (case when t1.type = 'pb' then t2.pb else t2.hb end) as amount
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id;
```

This seems like an arcane data structure.  You might consider normalizing the data in table 2, so there is one row per id and type.